# How to import and compile a class during a game with objective-c or cocos2d?

Tags: objective-c, class, import, cocos2d-iphone

I'm building a game with cocos2d (for iPad) and I would like to know if a class exists, in objective-c or cocos2d that allows me to import another class (written in objective-c).

During the game-session, this has to be compiled in a dynamic way and the methods of this class have to be used in the game to implement it.

I've found the NSBundle of objective-c but they can't be used in this way for iPad.

Can you give me some advice, If you know a solution with cocos2d or library of objective-c?
if there is no solution a parser may be possible?

Comment: Apple explicitly disallows any dynamic code compilation (they won't put it on the App Store) - you may want to rethink what you are trying to do.

Comment: I concur. And everything you're allowed to do with the Objective-C runtime is documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to answer your questions so late.. I hope this helps..

lets say you want to check if the class 'ADBannerView' is available. Then you can do something like this.

```
Class classAdBannerView = NSClassFromString(@"ADBannerView");
if (classAdBannerView != nil){
     //the class is available.
}
```